# Excel IF and AND form with four output options

Tags: excel, if-statement

I'm trying to get the following setup in Excel.

As background the values in E59 (this refers to D) and E60 (this refers to L) only go up to 100

```
If E59>E60 and E59=100 then display L
If E59<E60 and E60=100 then display D
If E59 and E60 are both <100 then display both
If E59=100 AND E60=100 then display Neither
```

I've got this so far

```
IF(E59>E60,"L",IF(E59<E60,"D",IF(AND((E59=E60), (E59=100),"Neither"))
```

Any help most gratefully received!

thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If they can both only go up to 100, try this

```
=IF(AND(E59=100,E60=100),"Neither",IF(E59=100,"L",IF(E60=100,"D","Both")))
```

Comment: Apologies, new to site so still learning. I ticked the "answered my question" green tick but it isn't letting me change the score from -1. Hopefully people can see these comments tho!

Comment: No problem, probably somebody else did that. Thanks for accepting the answer.

Comment: Hi, I have another question along the same lines that I also can't get to work. Trying to understand the syntax and Excel just gives an error. Can I post it here I do I need a new question?

Comment: Probably best to ask a new question.